# Проблема с перемещением файла

Tags: php

Никак не перемещает книгу и не создает новую запись в базе данных. Почему, не понимаю. Старую удаляет а новую не создает.

```
if($_GET['w'] && $_GET['id']){
if ($_GET['w'] == "on"){
$idi = $_GET['id'];
$on = "SELECT * FROM `test_b` WHERE `id` = ".$idi;
$on = mysql_query($on);
$on = mysql_fetch_assoc($on);
$d_on = "INSERT INTO `books` (`id`,`name`,`avtor`,avtor_2`,avtor_3`,`info`, `ctil`, `cym`,`kol`,`date`) VALUES 
(NULL,'".$on['name']."','".$on['avtor']."','".$on['avtor_2']."','".$on['avtor_3']."','".$on['info']."' ,'".$on['ctil']."',0,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
$d_on = mysql_query($d_on);
$id_b = mysql_fetch_assoc($d_on);
if (rename('book_t/'.$idi.'.pdf','book/'.$id_b['id'].'.pdf')){
rename('book_t/img/'.$idi.'.jpg','book/img/'.$id_b['id'].'.jpg');
$lol = "DELETE FROM `test_b` WHERE `id`='".$idi."'";
$lol = mysql_query($lol);
$onn = "SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE `id` ='".$on['id_av']."'";
$onn = mysql_query($onn);
$onn = mysql_fetch_assoc($onn);
$post = $onn['kol_b'] +1;
$got = "UPDATE  `register` SET `kol_b` = '".$post."' , `da` ='".$onn['da']."' WHERE  `id` = '".$onn['id']."' ";
$got = mysql_query($got);
$onnn = "SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE `id` ='".$onn['id']."'";
$onnn = mysql_query($onnn);
$onnn = mysql_fetch_assoc($onnn);
if($onnn['kol_b'] >= 5 and $onnn['rang'] < 1){
$gott = "UPDATE  `register` SET `rang` = '1' , `da` ='".$got['da']."'  WHERE  `id` = '".$onn['id']."' ";
$gott = mysql_query($gott);}
if($onnn['kol_b'] >= 15 and $onnn['rang'] < 2){
$gott = "UPDATE  `register` SET `rang` = '2' , `da` ='".$got['da']."' WHERE  `id` = '".$onn['id']."' ";
$gott = mysql_query($gott);}
if($onnn['kol_b'] >= 30 and $onnn['rang'] < 3){
$gott = "UPDATE  `register` SET `rang` = '3' ,`da` ='".$got['da']."'  WHERE  `id` = '".$onn['id']."' ";
$gott = mysql_query($gott);}

header("Request-URI: admin.php?v=book");
header("Content-Location: admin.php?v=book");
header("Location: admin.php?v=book");
}}
else if ($_GET['w'] == "off"){
$idi = $_GET['id'];
$lol = "DELETE FROM `test_b` WHERE `id`='".$idi."'";
$lol = mysql_query($lol);
if(unlink("book_t/".$idi.".pdf")){unlink("book_t/img/".$idi.".jpg");
header("Request-URI: admin.php?v=book");
header("Content-Location: admin.php?v=book");
header("Location: admin.php?v=book");}else{echo "НЕ вышло удалить файл!";}
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. какие права на папку book ?
2. какое название книги ? Если книга содержит " то sql запрос поломается. Желательно квотить имена книги функцией mysql_real_escape_string
3. Уберите id из insert запроса, соответственно нужно убрать NULL из VALUES секции
4. что бы узнать id вставленной записи нужно использовать функцию mysql_insert_id после mysql_query с запросом на INSERT

Comment: название книг состоит из цифр типа  56 43 23 ,тоесть там id в бд. и книга и фотка тоже так называются.

Comment: на все 4 папки права 777

Comment: вот теперь проблема в другом..книгу скинуло (я правда не правильно вытаскивас бд ид) а бд запись не сохранилась и получается что у книги ид предадущей книги
$nada = "SELECT `id` FROM `books` ORDER BY id  DESC LIMIT 1";

Comment: Так с чем у вас остались проблемы ?